# How print html page on two lists using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to print one part of a html page in one list and another part in a second list. How I can do this?

For example, some text on first and prices on second page.

Comment: say what? What have you tried? Show some code! Show examples etc.

Comment: What examples you're want to see, window.print()?

Comment: how you want to split the text.. and more important, examples of pieces of code you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a print css (e.g. by adding a css file for printing only: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />`) which hides (e.g. using `display: none;`) all parts which shouldn't be printed and adds a css [page-break-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/page-break-after) or [page-break-before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/page-break-before).

Answer (score 1):

You could link to a page where the first part is shown and link to another page where the second part is shown. Then you can use the javascript "window.print()" method in the document ready to print the page.